# Скорость работы с разными типами в C++

Tags: c++

Занимаюсь оптимизацией кода. Интересны такие вещи
что быстрее, и в каких случаях: `short int` или `int`, `unsigned int` или `int`?

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/kGsdDTp.jpg)

Боюсь, на байтах вы сэкономите куда меньше, чем на оптимизациях алгоритмов и правильно (или хитро) расставленных break'ах. Даже если операции с какими-то типами выполняются медленней, это, скорее всего, выражается в простом множителе сложности алгоритма, который обычно и вовсе опускается (я молчу уж о том, что нужно ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО данных, чтобы появилась сильная разница).

Что до конкретных типов, то short int и int, насколько понимаю, имеют минимальную разницу в быстродействии, а unsigned int и int отличаются только интерпретацией.

Comment: @Dexter384, если говорить о целочисленных типах, то в желудке *сферического коня в вакууме* быстрей будут перевариваться операции на типах, размер которых равен машиннному слову на данной архитектуре. Но - см. комментарий @Fike выше.

Comment: А что в этой оптимизации преждевременного?(Это я про картинку=))

Comment: Код я уже написал=)

Comment: Согласно документации, использование `int` (и его `signed`/`unsigned`-вариантов) эффективнее всего, т. к. размер его компилятор выбирает равным нативному машинному слову.

Но если вы хотите оптимизировать, не занимайтесь нанооптимизациями наподобие тонкой настройки типов. Делайте вот что:

1. Применяйте подходящие структуры данных и алгоритмы.
2. Профилируйте.
3. Профилируйте.
4. Профилируйте.
5. Профилируйте.

Comment: ок. не буду этим заниматься. пойду профилировать, профилировать, профилировать, профилировать...=)

Comment: Сама арифметика (наверное на всех современных 32/64 бит платформах, но 100% не гарантирую) для целых (не важно signed или unsigned) размером меньше или равным *машинному слову* (long в Linux C/C++) будет одинакова по времени при естественном выравнивании (содержимое не пересекает границу слова).

--

А вот если речь о массивах и циклах....

Чем меньше размер данных, тем больше их поместится в кэш процессора. Разница при доступе к данным между уровнями кэша может различаться на порядок. 

--

Вот и считайте.